# ArrayList<string> getIntent crashing the app

Tags: java, android

I am using Android studio 2.3.2 and I am not able to get what's wrong. If I comment:

```
 ar = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("name");
```

everything works but obviously it doesn't do the job.

My files are:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        ar = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("name");
    }

    public void clickFunction(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),secondactivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}

public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view){


        ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
        ar.add("Apple");
        ar.add("Banana");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",ar);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);

        // Intent intent = getIntent();

    }
}`

    `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("name")
```

Comment: Thku very much its working for the future can u tell me where to look for these functions.

Comment: You can refer  
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html